# Slice array and get only the sliced array

Tags: php, mongodb

In MongoDB I'd like to paginate an array. So I do this:

```
$foo = $coll->findOne(
    $idQuery,
    [$key => ['$slice' => [$page * $limit, $limit]]]
);
```

That returns the whole document with the `$key` array sliced. How can I tell MongoDB to get me only the sliced array `$key`? Like when you'd set `[$key => 1]` in projection, and you'd only get `$key`.

Comment: @Scott I don't think `array_keys()` would help me to get only an sliced array from MongoDB. I think my question wasn't clear enough...

Comment: Oh, right. This is a MongoDB specific question. Sorry, I don't have any experience with it :(

Answer (score 0):

With the new MongoDB PHP driver, we can do it the following way:

```
<?php

try {

    $filter = [];
    $options = ["limit" => 5, "skip" => 2];

    $mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);     

    $rows = $mng->executeQuery("testdb.cars", $query);

    foreach ($rows as $row) {

           print_r($row);
    }    


} catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {

    $filename = basename(__FILE__);

    echo "The $filename script has experienced an error.\n"; 
    echo "It failed with the following exception:\n";

    echo "Exception:", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    echo "In file:", $e->getFile(), "\n";
    echo "On line:", $e->getLine(), "\n";    
}

?>
```

The example skips the first two rows and limits the output to five rows.
There are `limit` and `skip` values in the options parameter of
the `MongoDB\Driver\Query` to do the job.